# Open CMD/psexec on remote computer, return results

Tags: process, psexec

I want to programatically run psexec to start IPCONFIG on a remote computer and return the results to my computer.

Running psexec is no problem:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"d:\psexec.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"\\REMOTECOMPUTERNAME -i ipconfig \all";

p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

However, the window closes immediantly after it was executed, making it impossible to see the result.

Now I already tried redirecting the StandardOutput, but all I get is an empty string.
I tried several methods already, listing them all would just be tl;dr

So my question:
How can I either make the command window not closing itself after IPCONFIG has finished or how can I redirect the results from IPCONFIG into a string variable in my program?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by saving the output to a text file and read from the file after psexec has finished. Then delete the file.